# Functional Programming - Return Transformed array and the count of the array without calculating twice

Tags: php, functional-programming

I'm trying to write more functional code in PHP *without any helper libraries*.

I need to return some JSON that includes the results of a transformed array AND the count of that array (for convenience on the data consumer end). Since you're not supposed to use variables in FP, I'm stumped on how to get the count of the array without recalculating/remapping the array.

Here's an example of what my code currently looks like:

```
$duplicates = array_filter( get_results(), 'find_duplicates' );
send_json( array(
  "duplicates" => $duplicates,
  "numDuplicates" => count( $duplicates )
) );
```

How can I do the same without storing the results of the filter in a temporary variable to avoid running `array_filter()` twice?

Comment: you need another function to accept array and output pair<array, count>, then another function will transform this pair into json

Comment: don't  send `numDuplicates`  - it is property of the first argument (array) :)

Comment: 1. a `callable` is second parameter for the `array_filter`. 2. a `closure` with counter may be a solution.

Comment: @Deadooshka I always get the argument order wrong because array_filter( $array, $callback ) whereas array_map( $callback, $array )! Fixed in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**But first, acknowledge the following...**

1. **"Since you're not supposed to use variables in FP..."** – that's a *ludicrous* understanding of functional programming. Variables are used constantly in functional programs. I'm guessing you saw [point-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) functional programs and then imagined that every program can be expressed in such a way...
2. the receiver of the JSON could easily get the number of duplicates using `JSON.parse(json).duplicates.length` because every Array in JavaScript has a `length` property – it's arguably silly to attach a `numDuplicates` in the first place. Anyway, let's assume your consumer has a specific API that requires the `numDuplicates` field...
3. functional programming is concerned with things like function purity – maybe you've simplified your code in your post (which is bad; [don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or that is in fact your actual code. In such a case, `get_results()` and `send_json` functions are impure; `send_json` has an obvious (but unknown) side effect (the return value is not used) — You ask for a functional solution but you have other outstanding non-functional code... so...
4. There's nothing wrong with the code you have. Sometimes removing a point (variable, or argument), it hurts the readability of the code. In your case, this code is perfectly legible. It is at this point that I feel you're only trying to *shorten* the code or make it more *clever*. Your intention is to *improve* it, but I think you'd actually harm it in this case.

---

**What if I told you...**

a variable assignment can be replaced with a lambda? 0_0

```
(function ($duplicates) {
  send_json([
    'duplicates' => $duplicates,
    'numDuplicates' => count($duplicates)
  });
}) (array_filter(get_results(), 'find_duplicates'));
```

But that made the code longer.. and there's added abstraction which hurts readability T_T   In this case, using a normal variable assignment (as in your original code) would've been much better

---

**Combinators**

OK, so what if you had some combinators at your disposal to massage the data into the desired shape?

```
function apply (...$xs) {
  return function ($f) use ($xs) {
    return call_user_func($f, ...$xs);
  };
}

function identity ($x) { return $x; }

// hey look, mom! no points!
send_json(
  array_combine(
    ['duplicates', 'numDuplicates'],
    array_map(
      apply(
        array_filter(get_results(), 'find_duplicates')),
      ['identity', 'count'])));
```

Did we achieve anything other than writing the weirdest PHP you or anyone else has probably seen? Not to mention, the input is strangely nested in the middle of the expression...

---

**remarks**

I'm nearly certain that you'll be disappointed with this answer (or disagree with me), but I'm also pretty confident that you're not sure what you're looking for. A guess: you saw functional programming that "doesn't use variables" and assumed that's how all programs *can* and *should* be written; but that's just not the case. Sometimes using a variable or two can dramatically improve the readability of a given expression.

Anyway, all of this is *truly* beside the point because attaching `numDuplicates` is arguably an anti-pattern in JSON anyway (point #2 above).

Comment: Well, you certainly know what you're talking about, your answer is well-written and you do a very thorough job of pointing out my ignorance when it comes to Functional Programming. Thank you for taking the time to write this answer. Next time, take a little more time and add some *compassion* to your writing style. The interwebs will thank you and the world will be a slightly better place. At any rate, I clearly have much more learning to do to understand the functional paradigm, so I thank you for taking me to school on the matter.

Comment: @TomAuger aww I'm genuinely devastated that my tone comes across as uncompassionate T-T. I always hope that my willingness to spend a great amount of time in an answer demonstrates a unquestionable compassion. I'd ask you to re-read the answer while giving me the benefit of doubt; it might come across differently a second time. I'm sorry if I offended you. If you have remarks on how I can improve my communication style, I'm open to listening to them ^_^